# Tikz poster block title colours

Tags: color, block, tikzposter

I'm trying to get a custom colour on the title part of a `\block`. The documentation is really dense and I can't quite get my head around it.
So at the moment I have a `\block` that looks like
[image]

just made with the code

```
\block{The title of a block}{

\lipsum[1]

}
```

and I basically want to change the colour of the background behind the title part of the block, but without changing the colour of every block on the page. I guess this is really simple but I can't fight my way through the documentation to be able to find a simple answer, any help is appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. And, please, next time post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the color inside a local scope

```
\documentclass{tikzposter} % See Section 3
\title{Title} \institute{Inst} % See Section 4.1
\author{Auth} \titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic} % See Section 5
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle % See Section 4.1
\block{BlocktitleA}{\lipsum[1]} % See Section 4.2
\begin{columns} % See Section 4.4
\column{0.3} % See Section 4.4
{%<--------- Start scope
   \colorlet{blocktitlebgcolor}{red} %<---- change color
   \block{BlocktitleB}{\lipsum[2]}
}%<--------- End scope
\column{0.7}
\block{BlocktitleC}{\lipsum[3]}
%\note{Notetext} % See Section 4.3
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The [`tikzposter` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzposter/tikzposter.pdf) is quite short to read. See section 5.1 *Setting the colors*, you can read

> The colors for the backgrounds of the blocks can also be defined. The background color of the title portion of the block may be set with `blocktitlebgcolor`  and the background color of the portion of the block with the text is set by `blockbodybgcolor`. The text colors for the title and the block contents are set with `blocktitlefgcolor` and `blockbodyfgcolor`, respectively.

You can modify these colors using `colorlet`, for instance:

```
\colorlet{blocktitlebgcolor}{green}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just wasn't sure of the syntax but it makes sense now :)